# Don't block Camera with Blocking Volume in Unreal Engine

Tags: collision-detection, unreal-4

I use Blocking Volumes to prevent players from falling off platforms in a third-person perspective game in UE4.

These Blocking Volumes however block the camera, as if they were a physical wall.

How can I easily add block the player, without blocking the camera?

Ideally without coding/blueprints. If that's impossible, a simple blueprint would be best.

[image: UE scene 1]
  Camera at normal distance from player, when it's not being restricted by a blocking volume

[image: UE scene 2]
  Camera being restricted by a blocking volume

Answer (score 1):

In Details, in Collision, set "Collision Presets" to "Custom..." and then set "Camera" to "Ignore":

[image: Collision settings]